# Accord du verbe avec un COD

Tags: verbes, conjugaison

Dans «il les organise», pourquoi *organise* reste-t-il au singulier et ne s'accorde pas avec le pronom «les» ?

Comment: L'accord avec le COD est (dans certains cas) pour le participe passé. Par exemple : ``il les a organisés."

Comment: Pourquoi est-ce que *organise* devrait s'accorder avec *les* ? Parce que *les* est généralement suivi d'un pluriel ? Effectivement si *organise* était un nom et *les* un déterminant, on s'attendrait à un pluriel sur le nom. Mais ici, il s'agit d'un verbe et d'un pronom...

Answer (score 6):

Un verbe s'accorde avec son sujet pas avec son complément, ici le sujet « il » est au singulier donc « organise » est aussi au singulier.

Si le sujet avait été au pluriel, on aurait écrit :

> Ils les organisent

Bien sûr, en aucun cas on ne peut écrire :

> <s>Il les organises</s>

Pour les temps composés des verbes transitifs directs comme ici organiser, le participe passé a une fonction d'adjectif et s'accorde donc en genre et en nombre avec le COD placé avant. Le verbe lui-même (l'auxiliaire) reste cependant toujours au singulier:

> Il les a organisés
>
> Il les a organisées
>
> <s>Il les ont organisés</s>

Comment: Toutes les fois où j'ai voulu figurativement étrangler quelqu'un pour avoir écrit « Je vous aimes » sur un réseau social.... *eye twitch*

Comment: Je ne vous croiss pas! :-)

Comment: @Kareen C'est quand même mieux que le néanmoins correct « Je vous hais », non ?  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I find this a really good question, because modern romance languages have changed since the Middle Ages - and, in fact, French still keeps traces of a previous agreement rule with the COD (check the medieval Spanish example at the end, which I find really interesting).

- Le verbe s'accorde en général avec le sujet, sauf dans le cas d'un temps composé qui inclut un participe passé.
- Donc, pour l'exemple donné, "organise" doit s'accorder avec le sujet "il"
- Mais, quand le verbe est dans une forme qui compte un participe passé, si l'auxiliaire utilisé est le verbe "avoir," le participe passé doit s'accorder avec le COD SI LE COD EST PLACÉ AVANT LE PARTICIPE PASSÉ.
- Donc, si l'exemple donné était au passé composé, le participe passé s'accorderait avec le COD: "il les a organisés" ou "il les a organisées."
- Mais cette regle ne s'applique pas si le COD est après le participe passé: "il a organisé ses affaires."

This is a remnant of a different agreement rule in early romance languages. Here is a medieval example of early agreement with the COD, in this case for medieval Spanish:

"In the perfect tenses, the past participle often agreed with the gender and number of the direct object. For example, María ha cantadas dos canciones vs. Modern Spanish María ha cantado dos canciones ('María has sung two songs')" from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Spanish_language.

Incidentally, even in early romance languages, these agreement rules do not seem to apply uniformly. So the way they were derived must be quite complex - possibly a collision between two merging practices, or more likely different rules applying to different types of verbs. That would be worth looking into!

I enjoy finding these remnants of earlier practices - although they make it harder for us ordinary spellers.

Btw, a more detailed analysis of the agreement for the past participle, with an interesting historical discussion, can be found here: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accord_du_participe_pass%C3%A9_en_fran%C3%A7ais